Opensearch Query Returning Highlights which don't Match Highlight Query
I am running an elasticsearch query which looks like the following with require_field_match set to True. I pass the query as both the main and highlight query to ensure my highlights match my logic.
fruit_query = {

    "bool": {

        "must": [

            {

                "match_phrase": {

                    "textContent": 'I love fruit'

                },

            },

        ],

        "should": [

            {

                "match_phrase": {

                    "textContent": "apple"

                },

            },

            {

                "match_phrase": {

                    "textContent": "orange"

                },

            },

        ],

        "minimum_should_match": 1,

    },

}

However, my highlights seemingly ignore the logic of the query. I get many which look like "I love fruit, like dragonfruit" or "I love fruit for breakfast", completely ignoring the should part of the query.
I also tried using
"query_string: {
     "default_operator": "OR",
     "query": f'"apple OR orange",
}

instead of the should query, with the same results.
I tried editing the parameters of the query, googling the problem, and looking around online to no avail. It seems others https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/20676 might also be having the problem.
